# How do I run PHP code on another page when a user clicks on a button?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to have a php script from another page run when a user clicks on a button in jQuery. I have tried it but it is not working.

Below is my script:

**Button to be clicked from the index page**

```
 <button id="updatebutton" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onclick="update_btn_click('params');"><span class="fa fa-refresh">&nbsp;Generate Cards</span></button>
```

**The PHP Page(card_generator.php)**

```
function getRandomCodes(){
                        $ans = "0123456789";
                        $sus = strlen($ans) - 1;
                        return substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1) . substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1) . substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1) . substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1) . substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1) . substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1) . substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1). substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1). substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1). substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1). substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1). substr($ans, rand(0, $sus), 1);
                        }

                        function getRandomCode(){
                        $an = "01234abcdef5678ghijklm9nopqrxtuvwxyz";

                        $su = strlen($an) - 1;
                        return substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1) . substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1) . substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1) . substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1) . substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1) . substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1) . substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1). substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1). substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1). substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1). substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1). substr($an, rand(0, $su), 1);
                        }

                        for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
                             $gen =  mysqli_query($mysqli, "insert into pins(serials, pins)values('" .getRandomCode(). "', '" .getRandomCodes(). "')");

                        }

                        if($gen){
                            echo "ok";
                        }else{
                            echo $mysqli->error;
                        }
```

**jQuery**

```
function update_btn_click(param) {
$('#updatebutton').prop("disabled",true);
$.ajax({
    url:"generate_cards/card_generate.php",
    type:"post",
    beforeSend: function()
    {
        $("#message").fadeOut();
        $("#updatebutton").html('Generating <img src="../img/processing.gif" width="30" />');
    },
    success: function(response){
        if(response=='Ok') {
            //location.reload();
            $("#message").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                $("#message").html('<div class="alert alert-success"> <span class="fa fa-check"></span> &nbsp; Successfully Generated </div>');
                       //$("#btn-submit").html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add again');

                   });
                   cardTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
        } else {
            $("#message").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span> &nbsp; '+response+' !</div>');
            $('#updatebutton').prop("disabled",false);
        }
    },
    error: function(response){
        console.log('could not fetch data');
    },
    complete: function(response){
        // hide loading
    }
});
}
```

Could someone please direct me to the right path.

Comment: Not sure if i get it, but seems you just have to change the generate_cards/card_generate.php to a external url. If things go wrong, check if CORS is enabled

Comment: @danielarend, Do i need to use cors for that before it works?

Comment: If the target server blocks by CORS, yes.

Comment: @danielarend, I am testing locally for now...

Answer (score -1):

I have been able to solve it using the following method:

```
function update_btn_click(param)
    {
        //$('#updatebutton').prop("disabled",true);
        var resp = $("#updatebutton");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // Method type GET/POST           
            url: "generate_cards/cards.php", //Ajax Action url
            data: {},

            // Before call ajax you can do activity like please wait message
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                resp.html('Generating <img src="../img/processing.gif" width="30" />');
            },

            //Will call if method not exists or any error inside php file
            error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrow){
                resp.html("There are an error");
                $("#message").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span> &nbsp; '+data+' !</div>');
                //$('#updatebutton').prop("disabled",false);
            },

            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                //resp.html(data);
                $("#message").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    $("#message").html('<div class="text-success"> <span class="fa fa-check"></span> &nbsp; Successfully Generated </div>');
                           $("#updatebutton").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>&nbsp;Generate Cards');

                       });
                       cardTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: What did you change other than adding `data: {}`? That shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: It also looks like you removed `if(response == 'Ok')`. There's nothing in the PHP that causes an HTTP error if the query fails, so the `error:` function won't be executed. You should debug why `response == 'Ok'` wasn't working. Use the Network tab to see what's actually being returned by the PHP.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because it doesn't explain what the problem was, what you changed to fix it, and why that change was necessary.